# How to pass async data as a Array of Objects to child component - angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to pass an array of objects that I getting from my server to a child component, but I cant understand why its not working.
What am I missing here?

Parent component TS

```
  private movieListSub: Subscription;
  private movies: UserMovie[] = [];

  constructor( private movieService: UserMovieService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.movieListSub = this.movieService.getUpdatedMovieList().subscribe(response => {
      this.movies = response.userMovieList;    
    }) 
  }
```

Parent component Html

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="movies">
            <app-slider [data]="movies"></app-slider>
 </ng-container>
```

Child component ts

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data:UserMovie[];
  private movies:UserMovie[];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.data)  // Empty Array
  }
```

Service

```
   private userMovieList: UserMovie[] = [] 
    private updatedUserMovieList = new Subject<{ userMovieList: UserMovie[]}>(); 


    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

    getAllMovies() {
        return this.http.get<{movies:UserMovie[]}>(this.movieApiUrl)             
        .subscribe(response => {
           this.userMovieList = response.movies,
           this.updatedUserMovieList.next({userMovieList: this.userMovieList})
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`movies` is private so won't be accessible to the child component and will also throw an error in case of Prod Build.

Try this instead:

```
movies$: Observable < UserMovie[] > ;

constructor(private movieService: UserMovieService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.movies$ = this.movieService.getUpdatedMovieList();
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-container>
  <app-slider [data]="(movies$ | async)?.userMovieList"></app-slider>
</ng-container>
```

This way, you won't have to worry about unsubscribing from the observable.

Plus you'll get the `input` property in the `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngAfterViewInit`

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() data: UserMovie[];
  private movies: UserMovie[];

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for you're help. I try to do  you're suggestion, but it giving me a error that i can assign `movies$` with the response of the service. I added the service method

Comment: Ok. Now left everything like it was, but changed the `movie` from private to public and console log it on  `ngOnChanges` and i see the data. Is it the correct work flow ?

Comment: Yes. it is. I just suggested a way so that you don't have to manually unsubscribe from the Subscription.